# Call base property of overridden property in IronPython

Tags: ironpython

I have a class in C# with a simple property that is virtual

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

In IronPython, I try to override the properties like this and call it's base class:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def get_SomeProperty(self):
        # do something special and then:
        return super(Bar,self).SomeProperty

    def set_SomeProperty(self,value):
        # do something special and then:
        super(Bar,self).SomeProperty = value
```

It gives the following error:

> System.MissingMemberException: cannot set slot    at
>   IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType.SetMember(CodeContext context,
>   Object instance, String name, Object value)    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
>   ...

I also tried to implement it as `super(Bar,self).set_SomeProperty(value)`, but this gives the error that set_SomeProperty doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to implement your getter/setter like this:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    @property
    def SomeProperty(self):
        # do something special and then:
        return super(Bar,self).SomeProperty

    @SomeProperty.setter
    def SomeProperty(self,value):
        # do something special and then:
        super(Bar,self).SomeProperty = value
```

To make them getter/setter, you should use `@property` and `@<MEMBER>.setter`. Hope this helps.